# Clave foránea mal formada en Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-7

Hola comunidad estoy intentando hacer la relación a nivel de base de datos y según la documentación de Laravel 8 tengo que agregarle la clave foranea, pero sin embargo me da error de clave mal formada, ¿cual sería mi error?:

```
Schema::create('educactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('institution');
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cities_id');
            $table->foreign('cities_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

También le agregué la relaciones en los modelos:

```
// En el modelo City
    public function educations(){
        return $this->hasMany(Education::class);
     }

//En el modelo Education
    public function city(){
        return $this->belongTo(City::class);
    }
```

Detalle del error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `db_XXXX`.`educactions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `educactions` add constraint
> `educactions_cities_id_foreign` foreign key (`cities_id`) references
> `cities` (`id`))

Tendría que poner el nombres de la tabla en singular o como podría solucionarlo

Comment: Si la creación de las tablas están en el orden en el que las muestras en la pregunta, cuando creas la tabla `educactions`, la tabla `cities` aún no existe, por lo que no podrías hacer `->references('id')->on('cities')`

Comment: Solo cambia el orden (Primero crea `cities` y luego `educactions`), estas intentando ponerle FK a `educactions` cuando la tabla `cities` aun no esta creada